# JRUBY GUI Toolkits

Tags: user-interface, jruby, libraries

I have been looking for a GUI library for a while now. I had tried Monkeybars and Glimmer, both of which appealed the most to me, but I didn't manage to get them running (Glimmer is very old, won't load the gem properly) and Monkeybars seems quite dead, can't even run the Hello World examples in the video presentations.

So I am wondering if you had any success with any JRuby libs (I am more in favour of Jruby because distribution is easier) What would you recommend?

Answer (score 3):

wrenta:  "Monkeybars seems quite dead, can't even run the Hello World examples in the video presentations."

Did you try to contact any of the Monkeybars developers, such as me?  I'm guessing you didn't or I would have heard of it. I'm the project leader.  The examples may be out of date, but the code itself is quite alive and very usable.

Mark: "Monkeybars isn't necessary if you can follow a Java API."

You don't understand the role of Monkeybars.  Yes, it makes it easier to use a GUI built in aWYSIWYG IDE, but the real value, and the reason it exists, is that it provides a sane way to split up code a al MVC so that you can create large, multiple windowed, arbitrarily complex applications.  Raw Swing is OK for something as lightweight as a calculator, but if you try that with a serious desktop project you'll soon want to hang yourself.  Monkeybars helps keep it clean, testable, and Ruby.

Comment: Isn't the Monkeybars website dead?

Comment: Monkeybars is an awesome project. It should be more active

Comment: No [commits since 2015](https://github.com/monkeybars/monkeybars-core). It's dead now.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the beauty of JRuby is that you can use any of the Java libraries available. Here's a [recent tutorial](http://wiki.netbeans.org/SwingJRuby) on creating a Swing application with JRuby. Monkeybars isn't necessary if you can follow a Java API. If you want some nifty pre-built components check out [SwingX](https://swingx.dev.java.net/).